# Plant identification again, please!

Tags: identification

Hello again to the gardening knowledgeable people; I do not have a choice but  to ask for help to identify one more plant  in my garden. I have moved recently and seeded some plants but many different other plants are growing also in a such a small garden. Please help me to find out if the below plant is a weed or a flower so I do not make a mistake and pull it out.

Thank you in advance!

Cristina[image]

Comment: Which region/continent?

Comment: Christina, please *always* include the location (roughly) for outdoor plants. You can always [edit] your post to add details.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it's a little bit of a futile task to identify plants by a single picture of leaf closeup only, but in this case, it really looked familiar like a weed I have seen *somewhere* in my yard.... (Where have I seen those innocent looking leaves before???)

Using the very cool [U of Wisconsin weed identifier](http://www.weedid.wisc.edu/weedid.php), it looks a lot like Epilobium ciliatum. According to internet, it grows in lots of different places in the world, and sometimes called Willow-herb. Looking it up, I don't find any horrendous characteristics of this weed - like toxicity or extreme invasiveness, etc. But it does make those fluffy parachute-type seeds that float on the wind, so I guess that could be sort of negative.

I don't know if this is your plant, but if nobody else comes up with a better match, maybe look this one up & see what you think.

[image: Epilobium ciliatum weed]

photo from https://oregonstate.edu/dept/nursery-weeds/weedspeciespage/nwh/nwh_foliage.html

Comment: Was my first thought as well. Knowing them “personally”... ‘nuff said.

Comment: Lorel are you living in Oregon?

Comment: I'd pull 'em.  Classed a weed in my book.  Too good at survival don't allow to go to seed.  Good ID Lorel.

Comment: @stormy a prime example of a pioneer plant - E. angustifolium is often mentioned in German literature on the topic.

Comment: If it’s really E. ciliatum, it’s an invasive plant in the UK (I think OP is located there, iirc.) and should not be allowed to go to seed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a desert rose. It looks similar to the one here
https://chingchailah.blogspot.com/2016/03/growing-desert-rose-or-adenium-obesum.html?m=1

Comment: This is definitely NOT an Adenium. I don't know what it is, but I'm certain it's not an Adenium of any sort. Adenium are a succulent plant with a swollen caudex.

Comment: I appreciate your time to answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of looks like the leaves of Celosia or New Guinea Impatiens.

Comment: Similar, New Guinea impatiens have leaves that are similarly tapered both at the stem and tip, the plant in question is blunter at the stem end. Also the grooves are a bit more pronounced in the impatiens.